# CheckBox in Dropdown

Tags: asp.net

Hi All 
I need a CheckBox Dropdown list control in asp.net i have seen the Jquery control provided in 
http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html but i also need Hierarchy in that control 
*Animal
  *Vertiberates
     *Aunts
*Plants
  *Fungi
Is there any control other than this which can provide this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was working on similar requirement, I have used "Popupcontrol" from Ajax Toolkit.
Here is more info http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx

Basically, you can create a panel, add all your controls (for example a treeview in your case) and put a textbox which would invoke the panel using the Popupcontrol extender.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a control but you can get most of that functionality with a div with a scroll bar. like this.

```
<div style="width:75;height:75;overflow:auto">
<input type =checkbox ">a<br>
<input type =checkbox ">b<br>
<input type =checkbox ">c<br>
<input type =checkbox ">d<br>
<input type =checkbox ">e<br>
<input type =checkbox ">f<br>
</div>
```